# How can I generate class diagrams from the .h?

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I am using the software Enterprise Architect (EA-UML), and I need to generate a class diagram from ".h". How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/‎). It can generate some inheritance diagrams from your code, but I'm not sure how easy it is to customize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go tools->sourceCodeEngineering->ImportSourceDirectory

EA will then scan the directory and put the classes into the model. You can then create a new class diagram and drag-drop the classes from the model to the diagram.

Comment: Hi,

I did the following. Created an example of a class diagram, a sequence diagram, a state diagram, the use case.
After I generated the code from the class diagram, in the directory it generated codes C++ Source and .h
Then tried to generate through the ".h" class diagram. I did so:
1- I created a new package and add a new diagram(empty)
2- In Tools -> Source Code Engineering -> Import C++ Files

It imports the classes, but does not generate the diagram

Thanks,

Comment: No, it will generate the model elements in you package. As I wrote above, you have to move the elements into the class diagram manually.

Please note, that UML consists of two basic entities: The model and the views to the model (= the diagrams). The source code engineering only creates the model from the sources, the diagrams must be created by the user, as EA cannot know how you want to view (sic!) you model.